# Formatting in a UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextview

im having problems with formatting for a UITextView. my app pulls in XML, saves some of it to a string , and then displays the text in a UITextView.

it understands if you put a return in there, and it starts a new line. but i want to put paragraphs in there, any idea how i can pass that information without doing multiple UITextViews

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are converting to text from XML content, then it is probably easier to use a UIWebView and format using html.

If you want total control of formatting, then you need to move to using Core Text (3.2/iPad).